# Loading csv into R with `sep=,` as the first line

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

The program I am exporting my data from (PowerBI) saves the data as a .csv file, but the first line of the file is `sep=,` and then the second line of the file has the header (column names).

Sample fake .csv file:

```
sep=,
Initiative,Actual to Estimate (revised),Hours Logged,Revised Estimate,InitiativeType,Client
FakeInitiative1 ,35 %,320.08,911,Platform,FakeClient1
FakeInitiative2,40 %,161.50,400,Platform,FakeClient2
```

I'm using this command to read the file:

```
initData <- read.csv("initData.csv",
                   row.names=NULL,
                   header=T,
                   stringsAsFactors = F)
```

but I keep getting an error that there are the wrong number of columns (because it thinks the first line tells it the number of columns).

If I do `header=F` instead then it loads, but then when I do `names(initData) <- initData[2,]` then the names have spaces and illegal characters and it breaks the rest of my program. Obnoxious.

Does anyone know how to tell R to ignore that first line? I can go into the .csv file in a text editor and just delete the first line manually before I load it each time (if I do that, everything works fine) but I have to export a bunch of files and this is a bit stupid and tedious.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try skip=1 (extra argument to read.csv) - this will skip the first line

Comment: it does not "think the first line tells it the number of columns" - it just expects all lines to have the same number of columns.

Comment: See `data.table::fread`, it *tries* to read in the data as intended by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do that. Here's one:

```
all_content = readLines("initData.csv")
skip_first_line = all_content[-1]
initData <- read.csv(textConnection(skip_first_line),
                   row.names=NULL,
                   header=T,
                   stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: Excellent. It strikes me that I could also build in an `if` command to check that the first line is indeed `sep=,` before I skip it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your file could be in a UTF-16 encoding. See [hrbrmstr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50070113/r-3-5-read-csv-not-able-to-read-utf-16-csv-file) in how to read a UTF-16 file: