# R 3.5 - read.csv not able to read UTF-16 csv file

Tags: r, read.table, read.csv

My code is as follows:

```
read.csv("http://asic.gov.au/Reports/YTD/2018/RR20180420-001-SSDailyYTD.csv", skip=1, fileEncoding = "UTF-16", sep = "\t", header = FALSE)
```

- R 3.4.3 - Code executes cleanly
- R 3.5.0 - gives the following error:

`Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : no lines available in input`

@hrbrmstr - session info readout

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] stringr_1.3.0      RCurl_1.95-4.10    bitops_1.0-6       tidyr_0.8.0        lubridate_1.7.4   
 [6] zoo_1.8-1          ggplot2_2.2.1.9000 data.table_1.10.5  magrittr_1.5       dplyr_0.7.4       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.16      bindr_0.1.1       munsell_0.4.3     colorspace_1.3-2  lattice_0.20-35  
 [6] R6_2.2.2          rlang_0.2.0       plyr_1.8.4        tools_3.5.0       grid_3.5.0       
[11] gtable_0.2.0      withr_2.1.2       yaml_2.1.18       lazyeval_0.2.1    assertthat_0.2.0 
[16] tibble_1.4.2      bindrcpp_0.2.2    purrr_0.2.4       glue_1.2.0        stringi_1.1.7    
[21] compiler_3.5.0    pillar_1.2.2      scales_0.5.0.9000 pkgconfig_2.0.1
```

- Is this a bug in the new R version or
- Am I missing something

Please help me!

Comment: I am not on R 3.5.0 to test, but you might try `fileEncoding = "UTF-16LE"`

Comment: I tried that as well but did not work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I received errors as well. This, however, works:

```
csv_url <- "http://asic.gov.au/Reports/YTD/2018/RR20180420-001-SSDailyYTD.csv"

download.file(csv_url, basename(csv_url))

read.csv(
  basename(csv_url), skip = 1, fileEncoding = "UTF-16", sep = "\t", header = FALSE
)
```

If you do not have an account on https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/ or it won't let you make one, let me know and I'll file a bug report for you after testing on a linux system (I'm on macOS and if you could add the output of `sessionInfo()` to your question that'd be )

I will note that even `readr::read_tsv()` has issues with this file so there may be legitimate encoding issues that older R versions were less stringent about.

Comment: Thanks, it worked when I downloaded the file and then read it. Grateful if you could flag this with the core team.

Comment: No worries. I'll reprex it on all the relevant CRAN operating systems and then follow up here with a link to the issue (likely Monday). Glad this worked!

Comment: Also #ty for the `sessionInfo()` output. That's a huge help!

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04, compiled from source, I get this same error in R-3.5.0.

Comment: thx. I'll add that to the list. Likely filing a bug report tdy or (at the latest) tomorrow.